# PHP DOMElement getElementsByTagName specific selector

Tags: php, dom, screen-scraping, domdocument

```
$content = file_get_contents(http://www.domain.com/page.html);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
if (!@$dom->loadHTML($content)) die ("Couldn't load file?");

$title = $dom->getElementById("cssid"); 
$data['heading'] = $title->nodeValue; // this works fine
```

I would like to be able to select all `p` tags that are within a certain id. With Jquery Ii would do something like $('#mycssid p');

**How would I do this using the DOMDocument class**

Comment: *(sidenote)* You can use [DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) to load HTML files with DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodelist = $x->query("//*[@id='cssid']//p");
```